# InMobi SDK encountered internal error

Tags: android, google-play-services, inmobi

I have been trying this for last 24 hours with no success! I have followed every steps as mentioned in InMobi Support.

### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle (module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.01"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //InMobi
    compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:5.3.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
    //compile files('libs/InMobi-5.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xyz">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MapConnection_Activity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
       >


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key" />

        <activity android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.inmobi.signals.activityrecognition.ActivityRecognitionManager"
            android:enabled="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Error that I get in Log

```
08-01 09:50:36.101 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.PowerManager.isDeviceIdleMode, referenced from method com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.c.b
08-01 09:50:36.111 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.PowerManager.isDeviceIdleMode, referenced from method com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.e$a.a
08-01 09:50:36.301 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebResourceError.getErrorCode, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.RenderView$5.onReceivedError
08-01 09:50:36.351 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.createCalendarEvent
08-01 09:50:36.361 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.getGalleryImage
08-01 09:50:36.371 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.registerMicListener
08-01 09:50:36.371 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.storePicture
08-01 09:50:36.371 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.takeCameraPicture
08-01 09:50:36.381 26031-26031/com.abc.xyz I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.inmobi.rendering.a.unregisterMicListener
```

### InMobi Error

```
mMessage = The InMobi SDK encountered an internal error.
mStatusCode = INTERNAL_ERROR
```

### Extra Details

The only thing different in my code is `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1` and not `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0` as per  their support site which is because of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` that forces me to use a version above 9.0 and which I added because I am using `google-services.json` file which even InMobi asks for.

Also, I have tried their Sample App from site and it is also giving same error. Also, I am using `Android Studio 2.1.2` on Debian if it matters. Any help at all is most most most welcomed!

Comment: What API version is the device you are running the code on?

Comment: Android 4.4.2 API 19 @cricket_007

Comment: Right, so `Context.checkSelfPermission` was added in API 23, so was `PowerManager.isDeviceIdleMode`. Therefore, I don't think you can run that code in the way that you are.

Comment: What is the solution? I am not doing anything with checkSelfPermission and other things that are showing up on Verbose! InMobi is!

Comment: I understand. Have you found any documentation stating a minimum API of 23 is needed?

Comment: No. I haven't read any such thing on their support page!

Comment: I'm not really sure how to help with the InMobi library, but try to use an emulator with API 23+, see if that works.

Comment: Okay so I tested by building an APK on my Samsung Marshmallow device (I can't enable DEBUG MODE due to KNOX), ad Loading failed Internal SDK Error!

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that I never get a message in my log: `The publisher device ID is: ` which should be there if my google-play integration is working

Comment: Might be because InMobi is loading and crashing before it gets to initialize Google Play. Like I said, though, can't really help with that, sorry.

Comment: Nevermind.. still same error O.o

Comment: Clean and build your project. I have fixed by this way.